# Warum benutzt man „es“?

Tags: grammar, gender, pronoun

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Is it correct to say “Das ist meine Schwester” and not “Sie ist meine Schwester”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27530)*

Warum benutzt man in folgendem Satz *es* für die Zeitung?

> Die Bild-Zeitung kennt in Deutschland jeder. Es ist die größte Boulevardzeitung im Land.

Comment: Wenn der erste Satz nicht da wäre, wäre der zweite korrekter. Das wird aber durch *die Bild-Zeitung* vorne kaputtgemacht.

Comment: Weil der, der das geschrieben hat, einen Fehler gemacht hat. Grammatisch richtig wäre: ***Sie** ist die größte Boulevardzeitung im Land.*

Answer (score 11):

Der zweite Satz ist ein sogenannter Gleichsetzungssatz („Bild-Zeitung = größte Boulevardzeitung im Land“). In Gleichsetzungssätzen kann *es* sich auch auf etwas anderes als ein Neutrum beziehen; die Duden-Grammatik (4. Auflage) gibt hierzu in Randziffer 540 unter anderem folgende Beispiele:

> Seine Mutter lebt noch. Es ist eine tüchtige Frau.
> Ist hier jemand Berliner? Der Trainer ist es.
> Siehst du den Jungen und das Mädchen dort? Es sind meine Kinder.

Dasselbe gilt für *das* (Randziffer 550) und *dies*/*dieses* bzw. *jenes* (Randziffer 553):

> Siehst du diese Frau dort? Das ist meine Chefin.
> Siehst du den Jungen und das Mädchen dort? Das sind meine Kinder.
>
> Der Junge und das Mädchen – dies sind meine Kinder.
> Dies hier ist der Stall, jenes dort die Scheune.

In den meisten Fällen, einschließlich dem Satz aus der Frage, ließe sich auch ein nach Genus und Numerus „passendes“ Pronomen verwenden:

> Sie ist die größte Boulevardzeitung im Land.
> Der Trainer ist einer.
> Sie ist meine Chefin.

Es funktioniert aber nicht immer gut mit dem ursprünglichen Pronomen: Die Bezugnahme auf Personen mit *der*/*die* („Die ist meine Chefin“) kann umgangssprachlich oder distanzlos wirken, mit *dieser*/*diese* („Diese sind meine Kinder“) im Gegenteil hochgestochen und altmodisch. Der Satz „Der Trainer ist er“ wäre sogar falsch, weil hier „Berliner sein“ in erster Linie als Eigenschaft empfunden wird.

Comment: In »*Seine Mutter lebt noch. Es ist eine tüchtige Frau.*« würde ich das Wort »*es*« als Personalpronomen deuten, und somit den Satz für falsch halten. Die Sache mit der Gleichsetzung funktioniert nur, wenn man »es« als Demonstrativpronomen deutet, was man in diesem Fall aber normalerweise nicht tut. Ersetzt man »es« durch »das«, fällt die Möglichkeit einer Deutung als Personalpronomen weg, die Deutung als Artikel ist auch nicht möglich, somit kann »das« nur als Demonstrativpronomen gedeutet werden, was wiederum die Deutung als Gleichsetzung erleichtert, bzw. erst möglich macht.

Comment: Genau dasselbe Problem tritt auch im Fall des Satzes aus der Frage auf. Das Wort »es« am Beginn des zweiten Satzes drängt dem Leser die Deutung als Personalpronomen auf, vor allem, weil es sich tatsächlich auf eine Person (jedoch mit falschem Geschlecht) zu beziehen scheint. Auch wenn eine Erklärung als Gleichsetzung den Fall de jure zu lösen scheint, so trifft das de facto in der normalen Wahrnehmung der Grammatik des Satzes nicht zu. Auch wenn man eine Erklärung findet, die den Satz grammatisch als korrekt erscheinen lässt, so ist er zumindest stilistisch eine Katastrophe.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: _Er/sie/es_ ist immer ein Personalpronomen, aber es spielt letztlich keine Rolle, wie man es nennt. Warum wäre es mit dem Etikett "Demonstrativpronomen" für dich akzeptabler? Es hat doch dann denselben Mangel an Kongruenz. – Ich habe kein Problem mit dem Satzpaar aus der Frage und finde es auch stilistisch nicht katastrophal.

Answer (score 4):

Korrekt ist nur:

> Die Bild-Zeitung kennt in Deutschland jeder. **Sie** ist die größte Boulevardzeitung im Land.

**Es** wäre der größte Unsinn, wenn jemand das Gegenteil behauptete. ;-)

(***'Es'*** steht hier als Platzhalter für den ganzen Nebensatz.)