# Is the word "Unterlagen" masculine or feminine?

Tags: noun, gender, article, standard-german

I am studying german online via youtube, and in a lecture video about basic sentences, there were 2 sentences that baffled me based on my novice german grammar knowledge.

> Das sind Unterlagen.
>
> These are documents.

and

> Die Unterlagen sind wichtig.
>
> The documents are interesting.

In the first sentence, the article is neutral, whereas in the second sentence, the article is feminine. Is there any rule about sentences in German that changes the gender of an object based on their use in a sentence? If not, then what is the correct gender of the word "Unterlagen"?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27530/is-it-correct-to-say-das-ist-meine-schwester-and-not-sie-ist-meine-schwester https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8045/er-sie-es-versus-das

Comment: Unterlagen is plural, and therefore does not have a gender (the articles for all plural words are similar to the feminine singular, regardless of their grammatical gender in the singular). The corresponding singular would be "Unterlage" which is rarely used (in this context - the word has another meaning where it is commonly used). Unterlage is feminine. In addition, the Das in your first example is not an article at all, just as "these" is different from "the". The Die in the second example is the plural article.

Comment: Interestingly I even think that singular "Unterlagen" has a different meaning: You might sleep on an "Unterlage" but typically not on "Unterlagen" (odd office sleeps excepted).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The *das* in the first example is not an article since an article would have to come just before a noun. It's a demonstrative pronoun roughly translatable as "that", although "this/these" is more appropriate much of the time. Coincidentally, it has the same spelling and pronunciation as the article *das* for neuter nouns, but you should regard it as a different word.

In the second example, *die* is actually the plural article, not the feminine. It's used for all plurals regardless of gender. Again, it has the same spelling and pronunciation as the feminine article, but you should regard it as a different word.

In both cases *Unterlagen* is the plural of *Unterlage* so everything is inflected according to the plural. That's why *sind* is used both times instead of *ist*. The word *Unterlage* itself is feminine, but in most cases inflections only distinguish gender for singular nouns, so you don't really need to know the gender in these examples.

Comment: It is not correct that *das* is not declined. Consider for example *Dem ist nicht so* where it appears as dative.

Comment: @RHa: For some reason I had that in my notes, but it appears my notes aren't entirely correct. I'll make a correction to the answer. Another complication is that, as I understand it, articles can be used as pronouns as well, so *Die sind Unterlagen.* is grammatically correct, though it has a somewhat different meaning.

Comment: @RHa: PS. I was confused by the fact that you can use *das* as the subject of *sein* no matter what the number or gender, but that apparently only applies to *sein*. Otherwise you use the fully inflected *der, die, das, die* system which only differs from definite articles in the dative plural and genitive. See [deutschplus](https://www.deutschplus.net/en/pages/Demonstrativpronomen_der_die_das), especially note 1. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is very helpful. I just wanna make sure that I got this right: we use articles (gender defined) only for a singular noun, and when it comes to plural, we use the word _die_

Comment: @Momobear In plural we use gender-specific articles as well, but the forms are the same for all genders, i.e. masculine plural = feminine plural = neuter plural: *die* (nom.) / *der* (gen.) / *den* (dat.) / *die* (acc.). Note: the dative plural article article is different from the dative singular feminine article (which would be *der*).

Comment: I get it now. Danke

Comment: With *sein* (*werden*, *bleiben* and a few more), there need not be genus (nor numerus) congruence between the subject and the predicative (not object!): "Meine Frau ist ein Genie", "Mein Chef ist eine dumme Sau", "Wir beide sind das bestmögliche Team"

Comment: Small addition: in the context where Unterlagen = documents, Unterlagen is afaik never used in singular.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: I thought about that and it seems weird that *bleiben* and *werden* wouldn't follow the same rule. Even if the predicate doesn't match the subject, the verb should, and if *sein* is not an exception then that would mean *Unterlagen* is the subject  in *Das sind Unterlagen.* This is possible but I think the meaning would be different. There's a similar issue with *Ich bin dein Vater,* and *Dein Vater bin ich,* apparently both are correct but if you replace *bin* with *ist* then both are incorrect. I'm still unclear on why.

Answer (score 11):

The *das* in the first sentence is not the article going with *Unterlagen*, it’s actually the subject, like for example in

> Das ist schön.

The *Unterlagen* shows no article because the indefinite article “disappears” for plural nouns, similar to the English language, it’s a “zero article”.

The grammar structure of *Unterlagen* is called **Gleichsetzungsnominativ** or **prädikativer Nominativ**. It is used with *sein* and a limited number of other verbs.

If *Unterlagen* weren’t in plural (or with a determined article), the grammar would be visible immediately, for example:

> Das ist eine Katze.
> -> Das sind [zero article] Katzen.
> Or
> Das ist die Katze des Nachbarn.
> -> Das sind die Katzen des Nachbarn.

The gender is not affected at all, both *die Unterlagen* and the cats in my random example are and remain female. Your question misinterpreted the function of the *das*.

Answer (score 2):

The difference shows best between

those are documents - das sind Dokumente

those are the documents - das sind die Dokumente